# A question about interpretation of relations matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, modules

Let $ R $ be an integral domain.

Suppose you have $n$ vectors $  v_{1} ,  v_{2} , \ldots,  v_{n}     $ (not necessarily $ R$-linearly independent) in a free $R$-module $M$ of finite rank $m$. Let $N$ be the submodule of $M$ generated by $  v_{1} ,  v_{2} , ...,  v_{n } $. Let $ \eta = \left \{ e_{1},  e_{2}, ...,  e_{m}  \right \} $ be a $ R $-basis of $ M$. Write the coordinate vectors of $ v_{i} $ with respect to $ \eta $ and concatenate these column vectors for each $  v_{i}     $ to get a $ m \times n $ matrix $ A $. Let's call this matrix the "relations matrix of $ \left \{ v_{i} \right \}_{i=1}^{m} w.r.t. \eta $.

Let $P \in GL(m,R)$, $Q \in GL(n,R)$. Let $B = PAQ$. Is it true that there are generators $   w_{1} ,   w_{2} , ...,   w_{n} $ of $N$, and a $ R   $-basis $ \gamma  = \left \{  f_{1} ,  f_{2} , ...,   f_{m}          \right \} $ of $  M   $ such that $ B $ is the relations matrix of $ w_{i} $ w.r.t. $ \gamma $?